# Limit the frame of a barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to produce a barplot with ggplot2. I came up with the problem that the margin of my diagram is proceeding to the right even the limit of the x-axes was set by `scale_x_discrete`. How can I limit the diagram frame to end with the bar of December?

Here is the code:

```
mean<-c(36.7, 17.3, 25.6, 41.5, 135.9, 203.9, 289.5, 277.8, 163.2, 67.4, 45, 44)
month<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
mean_CH<-data.frame(month, mean)


p<-ggplot(data=mean_CH, aes(x=month, y=mean)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="light blue") +
    ylab(expression(atop(paste("XXX "),paste("(XX"," ", XX^-1, " ", X^-1, " ", XX^-1,")", sep=""))))+
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11", "12"),
    labels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))+
    ggtitle("XXX")+
    theme_bw()
```

Here is my result:
[image]

Comment: Try `x = factor(month)` inside the `aes()`.

Comment: worked! Thanks a lot for this very quick solution! You can add this as an answer!

Comment: You can use `breaks = as.character(1:12)` and `labels = month.abb`, by the way.

Comment: @Axeman: Thanks for that great advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data, `month` is still a numeric variable, which causes the misalignment because `scale_x_discrete()` by definition expects discrete values on the x-axis. We can fix this by factorizing `month` inside the `aes()`.

```
ggplot(data = mean_CH, aes(x = factor(month), y = mean)) + ...
```